# How does Drupal compare to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, drupal

I have no experience with Drupal.

How does Drupal compare to SharePoint 2007 (or 2010) for the following "features"

- Document management
- Role and permission management
- Office integration
- Web Content management
- Custom server side development (features, custom pages, access to external data...)
- Deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the main difference between Sharepoint and Drupal is that Sharepoint ships with certain features that you can barely change.

In contrary Drupal has lots of extensions which are open source, that you can change and fit to your needs. So, your question is a little general, it depends how you're going to configure your Drupal, what modules you intend to use and so on....

In my opinion, Drupal can be very powerful but there is a little chaos in all the modules developed for it. Everybody can implement what features he feels is ok and in the end of the day the client-developer is staring at whole bunch of software wondering what to choose, what is better, how this works, etc ..

And back to your question, Drupal has all this features that Sharepoint has .. some are better implemented (like roles, permissions, and deployment) some not so good (office integration).

Answer (score 2):

Arpan Shah, Director of Technical Product Management for SharePoint, recently blogged about this.

Maybe he's biased, but the comparison is still valid:

[SharePoint and Drupal](http://blogs.msdn.com/arpans/archive/2010/02/23/sharepoint-and-drupal.aspx)

Comment: Maybe he's biased? Yes things are different 2 years later for both products. Basically SP is better for large corporations of office workers that are heavily invested in Windows environment; better integration. Drupal is better for everyone else for costs and configurability, but some solutions can cost more for custom development. But he tries claiming SP is better because D has some server reqs (free linux software) vs. $3k SQL server, and pumps up SP's community with no mention that Drupal is nothing but community. Save your time, ignore MS directors comparing MS products to open source.

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to "Cryophallion's" statement, SharePoint works with any file, not just MS Office. There enhanced capabilities when you are using MS office products but that is the only difference.

You Can change the functionality of SharePoint but just like Drupal, it takes developer effort. SharePoint actually gives you rich out-of-the-box functionality, that can be change if need be.

The document management is SP is good, not best of breed. It does give you native versioning, records retention and alerts. I'm not sure about Drupal

Role and permissions management is rich in SP (it can be as granular as you need) especially when combined with AD. Unsure about Drupal

Content management in SP is very good. In the same site you can stage your changes and publish only when ready, you don't need a separate site to accomplish this. It's done using major and minor versions. If need be you can elect to do this is a separate site, you have the flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about document management with Drupal, as it was designed as a website CMS, so I am unaware of Document Management and Office Integration for it. One other detail is what Productivity suite are you using? Sharepoint will not work with Open Office or any other Office suite than Microsoft's.

However, if you are looking for an alternative to Sharepoint, I would look at [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for Document Management you'll want some type of integration module.  I'd recommend exploring this one: http://drupal.org/project/kt.  KnowledgeTree is quite capable and provides the office integration you're requesting.